How do I display a ProgressView inside a menu in SwiftUI?
For my app, I would like to have a menu with a couple options that take a bit to load.
I've seen this behaviour in the TV app, like this:

However, no matter how hard I try I can't reproduce that. I've tried Label, Button, HStack, even Rectangle with an overlay, with no luck, the ProgressView just won't show up.
Here's some sample code of what I've tried:
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Menu("The menu") {
            ProgressView("some text")

            Button(action: {}) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Button")
                    ProgressView()
                }
            }

            Label {
                Text("Label")
            } icon: {
                ProgressView()
            }

            HStack {
                Text("HStack")
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

As you can see, the ProgressView never shows up:

Is there any way to have a ProgressView inside a Menu like Apple does?

Show some complete code that you have tried, so we can compile and run. Show the code in context, that is, show how the functions/Views/models etc ... are called and instantiated.

@workingdog support Ukraine Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my question.

The menu items that you supply to the Menu are "dissected" by the native implementation, which extracts the label components and displays them in its own native way. If you want to present a menu with richer content, you might have to implement it yourself. One way would be as a custom popover, the answer to iOS SwiftUI Need to Display Popover Without "Arrow" shows how this can be done.
